# Firebase child node make public

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to make public only `username` node under the user's child for register function. So this value must be able for the non-register users to register.  Here is my firebase database structure. How can I do that?

[image]

Here are my rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
       ".indexOn": ["username","email","bakiyetl","yarismada","yarismadabb","splashmesaj","uygulama1tut","uygulama2tut","uygulama3tut","uygulama4tut","uygulama5tut","uygulama6tut","uygulama7tut","uygulama8tut","uygulama9tut","uygulama10tut"]
        },     
    "gunluksifreler": {
      ".read": true, // <-- allows every person
      ".write": true
    },
      ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- allows read if logged in
      ".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write if logged in
  }
}
```

Search username in database.

```
Query cmyquery = refbir.child("Homeland").orderByChild("username").equalTo(usergivenname);


cmyquery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    //user name already taken
                    

                }else if(sonlandirgorev!=1){

                  //You can use this username


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Rule 1: To be able to read a location or run a query on a location, you must be able to read the data on that location.

Knowing that, let's look at:

```
Query cmyquery = refbir.child("Homeland").orderByChild("username")
```

This code requires that the user can read the `Homeland` node.

This is referred to in the documentation as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).

---

Rule 2: One you can read or write data at a certain level in the JSON, that permission can't be taken away at a lower level.

Given this rule and the above: one a user can read and query `Homeland` they can read all data below it. There is no way to hide part of that data.

This is referred to in the documentation as [read and write rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade).

---

The common solution is to split the data by who needs access to it. So if you want only the `username` property values to be available to everyone, create a top-level `usernames` node with the same keys under it, and then just the value of that user's user name. On that new `usernames` node you can then grant more liberal access than on the `Homeland` node.